# Why am I getting "Cast if C pointer type 'void' to Objective-C pointer..." error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use this code on my IOS project using the 4.6.2 Xcode

https://github.com/marshluca/AudioPlayer

but I can't compile but to this error:

[image]

I don't understand what bridge cast that is

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code -- they're hard to read and unsearchable. Use copy-paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace that with this

```
AudioStreamer *streamer = (__bridge AudioStreamer*)inClientData;
```

With ARC you have to use a bridged cast when casting a c type to an objective-c object.